# Голые ссылки на JSFiddle и иже

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, правки, сниппеты

Насколько помню, на большом Stack Overflow запрещены ссылки на jsfiddle (и, полагаю, другие аналогичные сайты), если в самом вопросе или ответе нет блоков с кодом. Согласно правилам, посты должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки на внешние ресурсы могут быть лишь дополнением к полноценному самостоятельному посту.

Однако я уже не в первый раз лицезрею [безобразие вроде этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413493/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-p-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-default-sum). Каждый раз перетаскивать код вручную несколько напрягает.

Внимание, вопросы:

1. Куда девалась проверка при отправке вопросов и ответов? Может, она как-то отдельно включается, как и подсветка кода, которой не было в самом начале?
2. И раз уж на то пошло, почему недоступны Code Snippet'ы, которые раз и навсегда должны были избавить пользователей от необходимости пользоваться сторонними ресурсами для выполнения связки JS+HTML+CSS? На PT.SO они работают. Значит, тоже какую-то опцию надо включить.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример вопроса или ответа с не работающим выполнением фрагментов кода?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Кнопка для вставки фрагментов уже заработала. Я думал, что это ваша работа. Кстати, мне не понять, почему эта штука называется "фрагментами кода". В жизни бы не догадался, что это значит. / Проверка на ссылки без включений кода в текст поста ещё не работают — до сих пор вижу такие посты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, проверка вопросов действительно была отключена. Сниппеты уже подключили месяц назад.

Есть шанс, что будут какие-то проблемы с поиском блоков кода в тексте на русском, так что, пожалуйста, дайте знать, если вопросы с ссылками на JsFiddle, но без кода, будут все еще появляться.

Comment: даю знать: [появляются](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430234/178576) в очереди «сообщения плохого качества.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, я посмотрю.